# How to make a dict[str, Any] = {} go to new line after each element?

Tags: python

I have dict[str, Any] = {} (populated) coming from this function:

```
def get_exif():
    global image_object
    try:
        exif = image_object.getexif()
    except AttributeError:
        return {}

    exif_table = {}
    for tag_id, value in exif.items():
        tag = TAGS.get(tag_id, tag_id)
        exif_table[tag] = value
        exif_lbl.configure(text=exif_table)
```

Shown like this on my GUI:

[image]

How can I make it show as this:

```
ResolutionUnit: 2,
ExifOffset: 146,
Software: GIMP 2.4.5
```

etc..
My exif_lbl is:

```
exif_lbl = Message(exif_frame, font=("helvetica", 18), aspect=200)
exif_lbl.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

Maybe I should change it to ListBox?

Thanks

Comment: it is not problem with widget. If you want expected result then you have to write code to convert it to string with `\n` - use `for`-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not problem with widget.

If you want expected result then you have to write code which will convert it to single string with `\n` - and it will need `for`-loop

---

```
data = {
   'ResolutionUnit': '2',
   'ExifOffset': '146',
   'Software': 'GIMP 2.4.5'
} 

# --- more readable

lines = []

for key, value in data.items():
    lines.append( f"{key}: {value}" )
    
text = "\n".join(lines)    

# --- shorter

text = "\n".join(f"{key}: {value}" for key, value in data.items())    

# ---

print(text)

import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
lb = tk.Message(root, text=text, width=500)
lb.pack()
root.mainloop()
```